# Adding a passenger to a flight booking made with Wizzair Discount

Tags: wizz-air

I have booked a ticket with my Wizzair Discount Club membership, and I want to buy another ticket for a companion on the same flight. How can I do it?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you trying to use discount points for two persons on the same flight?